# Riyadh airport visa - travelling with Wizzair and Etihad

Tags: visas, connecting-flights, self-transfer, ruh

I will be traveling with Wizz Air from Milan. I am European, and my flight is likely to arrive at Terminal 3. Three hours later, I have a connecting flight with Etihad to Manila. Since I hold a European passport, will not be checking any luggage, and will have completed check-in for the Etihad flight before arriving at RUH airport, I am wondering if I need a visa for this connection. I intend to walk between T3 and T2 without exiting the international transit area. Is this possible?

Comment: how was your flight with this travel?